# Django - can I have 2 many to many fields to another model?

Tags: python, django, database, model, many-to-many

I'm developing an application that has the following three models: Student, Subject and Skills. A Student can have many skills, and a Skill can have many student. A Subject can offer 0 or many skills after a Student complete it, however, a Student has to have 0 or many skills required to complete a Subject.

I tried doing the following:

### Subject

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subjects', default=0)
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True,verbose_name='Code', max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    offered_skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, related_name='subjects_o', blank=True)
    required_skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, related_name='subjects_r', blank=True)
```

### Skill

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True,verbose_name='Code', max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='skills', default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='skills', blank=True)
```

### Student

```
class Student(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Codigo', max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='students', default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

When I try makemigrations it leads me to the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/isaacrpl7/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1149, in __init__
    to._meta
AttributeError: module 'dashboard.models.Skill' has no attribute '_meta'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/isaacrpl7/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/isaacrpl7/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/isaacrpl7/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/isaacrpl7/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/isaacrpl7/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/mnt/c/Users/isaac/OneDrive/Documentos/GitHub/ano_letivo/dashboard/models/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .Skill import Skill
  File "/mnt/c/Users/isaac/OneDrive/Documentos/GitHub/ano_letivo/dashboard/models/Skill.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Skill(models.Model):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/isaac/OneDrive/Documentos/GitHub/ano_letivo/dashboard/models/Skill.py", line 11, in Skill
    offered_skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, related_name='subjects_o', blank=True)
  File "/home/isaacrpl7/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1151, in __init__
    assert isinstance(to, str), (
AssertionError: ManyToManyField(<module 'dashboard.models.Skill' from '/mnt/c/Users/isaac/OneDrive/Documentos/GitHub/ano_letivo/dashboard/models/Skill.py'>) is invalid. First parameter to ManyToManyField must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

What could this be? When I take off the two last attributes of Subject the error vanishes. How could I modelate this?

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'dashboard.models.Skill' has no attribute '_meta'` this is the error you need to solve, 2 many to many fields are okay and possible.

Comment: Does writing the model name as string in the Many to Many field solve your problem: `offered_skills = models.ManyToManyField('Skill', related_name='subjects_o', blank=True)`, (in both the fields) or if it is in another app then `'appname.Skill'`

Comment: It worked! Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Why does making them `string` work? For example, In `Skill` class, `students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='skills', blank=True)` is not a string. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Because of you declare skill after subject. Python interpreter dont know what you declare later in file. The 'skill' it's a trick to cheat python interpreter